# How to have complete exception stacktrace in ionic application (cordova / phonegap) and not a single line?

Tags: android, exception, cordova, ionic-framework

As I don't know where the issue lies, this question might not be about ionic but more about cordova / phonegap. I haven't done phonegap dev for a long time so I don't remember if this is the normal/expected behavour or if I miss something.

I get this kind of errors in my logcat :

```
11-30 14:39:28.592  16782-16836/com.ionicframework.myproject E/MyProject﹕ Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And that's it actually... All the exceptions generated in my application seem to be truncated somehow.  I tried displaying either the message or the exception and the result is the same...

The code generating the exception is in my plugin and I know its source but I can give it for reference :

```
 @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray jsonArray, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        try {
            JSONObject visible = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            toggleVisibility(visible.getBoolean("visible"), visible.getInt("duration"));
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

Any tips on this point ?

thx

Comment: I'd put a log line before and after each line in the try block. That way you could find out which line causes the null pointer.

Comment: Yeah but this is a very short version of my try/catch. As this is my execute method, there are maybe 10 or 15 cases in the try block, I'm not gonna put a log line every 2 lines to target the culprit. I can't publish this in my app. And as I said, in this case, I already know what's causing the nullpointer, I'm wondering if I can improve the stacktrace...

Comment: try e.printStackTrace();

Comment: e.printStackTrace() doesnt change a thing. You almost made me doubt myself. But for some reason, even if I debug, I only see the first part of the stack. Did you down vote me ?

Comment: I don't get people down voting questions for no reason. As a matter of fact, I finally figured it out, nothing to do with printStackTrace, which for some reason does not work here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `printStackTrace` for some reason does not work here. The issue here was the incorrect use of the Log class from Android.

This does not print the stacktrace :

```
Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
```

This prints the full stacktrace :

```
Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
```